# How to create a svn branch using nant script?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, branch, nant, new-operator

I need to create a branch copy of my trunk. While executing my nant script.

How can I create one branch using nant script?

I am using windows command prompt to execute nant script.

Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked the documentation of [SVN command in NANT contrib](http://nantcontrib.sourceforge.net/release/0.85-rc3/help/tasks/svn.html)? I don't have any experience with NANT, but this seems to explain what is possible. You have to get the parameters right, of course ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <project name="testproj" default="createBranch" >
      <target name="createBranch" description="New School" >
        <exec program="svn.exe" basedir="svndirectorypath" commandline="copy -madded --username ${svnUserName} --password ${svnPassword} "sourcefilepath" "targetpath""  />
      </target>
    </project>
```